# The convergence of Matrix factorization

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to prove the convergence of Matrix factorization.
The problem is described below.
$|X-WH|^2 + |H|_2^2 +|W|_2^2$.

My optimization steps are using Alternating least squares which update H with fixing W and update W with fixing H.

Although I can prove the convergence of subproblems(e.x. update H with fixing W), I have no idea to prove the convergence of this problem but not subproblems.

Does someone give some clues about how to prove the convergence of matrix factorization globally?

Thanks.

Comment: which Norm are you using (trace norm, spectral norm, or some other norm?).

Comment: Your algorithm generates a monoton decreasing sequence. Furthermore the functional is bounded from below by 0. Hence the values of the functional will converge. Given a constant $c>0$ we know that the domain where the functional is smaller than c is finite. Hence the sequence (H_i,W_i) has a subsequence converging to some(\bar{H},\bar{W}). Now one can prove that (\bar{H},\bar{W}) is a critical point. If you can prove that your functional is convex u are basically done as then ur functional has a unique minimum which is also the unique critical point. However I dont know how to prove convexity.

Comment: I use the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a special case of **Alternating Minimization**, on which many papers have been written.

One of the clearest (for your nonconvex problem) is this classic paper, which pays particular attention to the two block case: L. Grippo, M. Sciandrone, *On the convergence of the block nonlinear Gauss–Seidel method under convex constraints*. Operation Research Letters 26(2000), 127--136.

Comment: Super thank you to your answer. I will read this paper.