# Fixed point iteration on symmetric biconvex function

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convexity, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set and that a function $g(x,y):X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ is smooth, "strictly biconvex" (strictly convex in $x$ and $y$ independently but not jointly), and satisfies $g(x,y)=g(y,x)$.

Alternating optimization on $g$ in this case takes a nice form:  $x_{i+1}\gets \arg\min_x g(x,x_i).$

I know alternating optimization doesn't have to converge in general.  But, is there any chance to prove that $x_i\rightarrow x^\ast$ that under the symmetry and biconvexity assumptions?

Comment: Due to strict convexity each subproblem has a unique solution. This suffices to establish convergence (see e.g., *Nonlinear programming* by D. P. Bertsekas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper cited in [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/179167/8430) provides a detailed proof of the two-block case of alternating minimization (block coordinate descent). In particular, as mentioned in my comment, the convergence follows thanks ultimately to having unique subproblem solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This problem, in its general form (without requiring any convex properties), is very popular since 1950s. Look around the technique "Block Coordinate Descent" method to take a generic idea.

Your problem, that has these "partial"-convex properties is also popular. You can find a very good tutorial in [1] about such problems. 
In this tutorial, it is analytically explained that in principle it is difficult to optimally minimize such a problem. A very nice technique that guarantees the global optima is suggested in [2].

[1] Jochen Gorski , Frank Pfeuffer, Kathrin Klamroth, Biconvex sets and optimization with biconvex functions: a survey and extensions, 2007.

[2] C.A. Floudas, and V. Visweswaran, A Global Optimization Algorithm (GOP) For Certain Classes of Nonconvex NLPs : I. Theory, 1990.